# Why are my conditional checks are failing and firing a function?

Tags: reactjs, function, if-statement, react-hooks, react-query

I am using react-query hooks, my goal is to send the updated state to the database and receive the updated state as well.

My object is a workout diary that displays exercies on each given day:

```
{
        name: "my workout diary",
        currentDay: 0,
        days: [
            {dayName: "monday", exercises: {...}},
            {dayName: "day 2", exercises: {...}},
            {dayName: "rest day", exercises: {...}}
        ]
    }
```

The number in `currentDay` field indicates what day currently is being rendered on the screen from `days` array.

I have 2 buttons that move day back or forward using `useMutation` hook:

```
    const query = useFirestoreDocument([...],ref);
    const mutation = useFirestoreDocumentMutation(
        ref,
        { merge: true },
        {
          onSuccess() {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries([...]);
          },
        }
      );
      const workoutplan = query.data?.data();

      const moveDayBack = () => {
        if (workoutplan && !mutation.isLoading) {
          workoutplan.currentDay > 0 &&
            mutation.mutate({
              currentDay: increment(-1),
            });
        }
      };
```

Everything works just the way I want to if I do it **slowly**, but if I **spam** movedayback function fails the conditional check and sends the `-1` to the server then goes back to `0`, but that causes fatal error, because negative array index will return `undefined`.

[image]

Why are my conditional checks failing and how do I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how `increment` works, but it looks to me that your mutation has finished, but  the query invalidation has not. There are two ways to prevent clicking next / previous while the query is still running:

- check for `!query.isFetching` in addition to `!mutation.isLoading`, but this will also cover other kinds of refetches, like window focus refetching.
- *return* the query invalidation from the `onSuccess` callback:

```
onSuccess() {
    return queryClient.invalidateQueries([...]);
},
```

since `queryClient.invalidateQueries` returns a Promise, you can return it in `onSuccess`. The mutation will then internally `await` that Promise, which means the mutation itself will stay in loading state until the refetch has finished.